# Cannot install Windows 8 with Parallels

Tags: mac, installation, parallels

I am trying to install windows 8 with parallels (from an iso file on the mac), I have followed [this](http://kb.parallels.com/en/4729) instructions. They are partly missing. Foe example after selecting the iso I get `Automatic detection failed. Please select your operating system:` and I have a drop-down with various Windows, Chrome OS, Ubuntu, Free BSD ..... Windows 8 is not in the list so I chose Windows 7 that seems the closest, inserted the key, chose "Like a MAC", and another continue. Then everything seems promising, I see Windows8's installation and then some messages like "We are getting you PC ready". After some time the screen gets black, and thats it. At the to I still have the `Installing windows 7` message.

Another try was selecting "Other windows" instead of "Windows 7" from the OS list. This caused this message to appear:

[image]

In case it is important: I have a 32-bit installation ISO, and I did not check the 64-bit checkbox when it appeared at one of the screens.

- It is a new installation, on a new VM.

Comment: Which version of Parallels Desktop for Mac? Do you have the latest version?

Comment: @Karan Version 7, Build 7.0.14922

Comment: As per [this page](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/), v8 is the one that "Includes *experimental* support for 32- and 64-bit Windows 8 Release Preview."